# "/sbin/yast: fork: Cannot allocate memory" on openSUSE 10.1

Tags: opensuse, memory, fork, yast

How do I get the above message right after starting an ssh session.

The reason I opened the ssh session was that I came across a 500 internal server error on the plesk panel.

I tried to look around for similar problems, but all answers I find seem very specific toward variations on this problem. I guess it is a very generic message, if I should provide more info, please let me know what to run.

```
free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          5020        202       4817          0          0          0
-/+ buffers/cache:        202       4817
Swap:            0          0          0


ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 16375
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 32
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 16375
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited

cat /proc/user_beancounters
Version: 2.5
       uid  resource           held    maxheld    barrier      limit    failcnt
  1231234:  kmemsize        6061008    6064704   17024866   19647330          0
            lockedpages           0          0       3800       4096          0
            privvmpages      138119     138227     138256     202568     755228
            shmpages          60296      60296     131072     131072          0
            dummy                 0          0 2147483647 2147483647          0
            numproc              64         64        232        232          0
            physpages         30682      30671          0 2147483647          0
            vmguarpages           0          0      66400 2147483647          0
            oomguarpages      50128      50117 2147483647 2147483647          0
            numtcpsock           28         28        500        500          0
            numflock             14         14        200        232          0
            numpty                1          1         64         64          0
            numsiginfo            0          0        512        512          0
            tcpsndbuf        275520     275520    4683256    6102456          0
            tcprcvbuf        458752     458752    4683256    6102456          0
            othersockbuf      48576      49280    1503232    4063232          0
            dgramrcvbuf           0          0     240000     262144          0
            numothersock         38         38        382        382          1
            dcachesize       773048     774892    2194304    2317184          0
            numfile            2874       2874       5432       5432       6308
            dummy                 0          0          0          0          0
            dummy                 0          0          0          0          0
            dummy                 0          0          0          0          0
            numiptent            64         64        128        128          0
```

Comment: You need to increase `privvmpages` in the openvz configuration.

Comment: I could do that, but if the problem stems from something that causes privvmpages to accumulate then it'd only be a matter of time before I'm back where I started.
For now, I just rebooted the server. It had been running for about half a year without interruption. So the next step would be to find the root of the problem. Perhaps something to do with the few wordpress sites that it hosts.
I'll keep an eye on privvmpages see how fast it climbs up again.

Comment: Possibly related, or at least, I can't rule out this possibility: http://blogs.cisco.com/security/apache-darkleech-compromises/
Since it seems that this climb in the strain on the server was rather sudden after half a year.